# NativeScript Angular 2 Get more data when Scroll to Bottom (endless scrolling)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

HI for example below is my view

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *ngFor="let kid of kids" id="kidList">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="some-class">
                <Lable text="{{ kid.fname }} {{ kid.lname }}"></Lable>
                <Lable text="{{ kid.age }} years ago"></Lable>
            </StackLayout> 
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to append the more data getting from server to 'kidList' when scroll reaches to bottom of screen in {N} aAngular2.
It's very hard to me build the layouts and adding childs in 'js' like below(KidInformation has more data).

```
 let stackLayout = new StackLayout();
 stackLayout.addChild('something newly constructed with JS')
```

Is there a way we can do in My Component just by adding child as view by passing local parameters to view , I mean like in below way

```
let kidListStacklayout = view.getViewById(this.page, 'kidList');
kidListStacklayout.addChild('views/kid/kid-item.html')
```

and kid-item.html will look like

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="some-class">
                    <Lable text="{{ kid.fname }} {{ kid.lname }}"></Lable>
                    <Lable text="{{ kid.age }} years ago"></Lable>
                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: try `radListView` it has loadOnDemand and infiniteScroll options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock list view supports what you want. Don't use a scrollview and adding more layouts to the screen. This will cause lag and other issues. A listview recycles UI view components to reduce overhead of the layout growing in size. You want to use the `loadMore` event on the list view.  https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/list-view

Of course as the comment above ^^^ the free UI suite from telerik provides the RadListView which also supports infinite scrolling with a loadMore event.

Answer (score 3):

Find out how to do it ( using Angular & TypeScript) :

```
import { ScrollView, ScrollEventData } from "ui/scroll-view"; 

@Component({...})
class ComponentClass implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild("scrollid") scrollView: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){
 let scrollv : ScrollView = <ScrollView>this.scrollView.nativeElement;
 scrollv.on(ScrollView.scrollEvent, function (args: ScrollEventData) { 
        if(scrollv.scrollableHeight === args.scrollY){
            console.log("load more items here !!! ");
        } 
 });
 }    
}
```

The **scrollv.scrollableHeight** gets updated by itself. 
Tested on android emulator only. Must work on both Plateforms.

Comment: For ScrollView, Grid (and possibly other elements), you can try to wrap this in `ngAfterViewInit` as described here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1064#issuecomment-340679684